# Debugging osascript execution from within a ruby daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, applescript, daemon, osascript

I have a need to frequently run an applescript on my web server.  As the server is running rails, and I need access to my models before and after running the script, I thought that a daemon (via the [daemons gem](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/)) might be appropriate.

In theory this is fairly easy.  Below is a simplified example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "development"

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/application"
Rails.application.require_environment!

$running = true
Signal.trap("TERM") do 
  $running = false
end

while($running) do

  Rails.logger.info "Daemon running at #{Time.now}.\n"

  # sanity check
  %x{touch /foo.txt}

  # this stops working after a while
  result = %x{/usr/bin/osascript -s o /path/to/the/script.scpt}

  # under normal operation, my applescript spits out a string result
  Rails.logger.info "Result: #{result}.\n"

  sleep 30
end
```

For testing purposes I've replaced the (somewhat long and time consuming) production applescript with a one-liner.  Here it is, in all its glory:

```
"It Worked!"
```

Because applescript treats the last line of the script as a return statement, this string gets passed into my `result` variable and ultimately logged in rails.

This works great - for a while.  Eventually though (typically after several hours) the `osascript` line stops returning results.  The daemon *is* still running but the `osascript` line, for all I can tell, is completely failing without explanation.

I can say with certainty that the daemon itself has not died because

- The rails log entries appear at correct intervals, and
- My sanity check of "foo.txt" regularly updates its last modified time stamp.

---

I thought I'd post an update to this in case anyone out there is having a similar problem. First off, I've found a workaround.  Its an ugly hack for sure, but it gets the job done and it doesn't crash every 2 hours. What I'm doing is establishing an ssh connection every time the job is run, which effectively lets the script run on a clean session.

```
Net::SSH.start('127.0.0.1', 'username', :password => 'password') do |ssh|
  result = ssh.exec!('/usr/bin/osascript -s o /path/to/the/script.scpt') 
end
```

And secondly, I've found a large number of crash reports in my ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports directory. More and more I'm starting to believe that this whole ordeal has to do with some kind of session timeout or expiration.

```
Process:         osascript [24884]
Path:            /usr/bin/osascript
Identifier:      osascript
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  ruby [24868]

Date/Time:       2011-02-03 16:40:28.526 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
LaunchServices: GetOurLSSessionIDInit() returned err #1, securitySessionID == 0x0, vers=10600000 uid=501 euid=501web1.local] [Se
/Users/greg/Applescript/fbbuildutil.scpt

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fd6616 __kill + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff87076cca abort + 83
2   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff82faec84 GetOurLSSessionIDInit() + 298
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa08da pthread_once + 95
4   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff82faf29b SetupCoreApplicationServicesCommunicationPort() + 1343
5   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff82faf68d getProcessDispatchTable() + 19
6   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff82fb17a5 LSClientSideSharedMemory::GetClientSideSharedMemory(LSSessionID, bool) + 187
7   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00007fff82fb1e87 _LSCopyApplicationInformationItem + 43
8   com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8722b735 aeGetThisProcess() + 49
9   com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8722b6df AEEventImpl::initializeData() + 89
10  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8722b5c4 AEEventImpl::AEEventImpl(unsigned int, unsigned int, AEDesc const*, short, int) + 76
11  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8722f33e AECreateAppleEvent + 88
12  osascript                       0x0000000100001a42 0x100000000 + 6722
13  osascript                       0x0000000100000fa0 0x100000000 + 4000

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa116a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa303d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa2d14 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa283e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa2168 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa2005 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa1f8a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa239c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86fa2005 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00000000000001f5  rcx: 0x00007fff5fbfb378  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000006134  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfb390  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfb378
   r8: 0x000000010011d740   r9: 0x00000001001fc0a4  r10: 0x00007fff86fd2656  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x00007fff5fbfb3c0  r13: 0x00007fff703ce328  r14: 0x00007fff82faeb5a  r15: 0x00007fff70c465c0
  rip: 0x00007fff86fd6616  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x00000001000f8000

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100002ff7 +osascript ??? (???) <1B4A05C4-8772-DCFD-444F-31FEE356E299> /usr/bin/osascript
       0x1000f1000 -        0x1000f1fff  com.apple.applescript.component 2.1.2 (2.1.2) <C621AB4A-9C10-7F1D-6B4E-0B15373D5C59> /System/Library/Components/AppleScript.component/Contents/MacOS/AppleScript
       0x100419000 -        0x1004adfe7  com.apple.applescript 2.1.2 (2.1.2) <E9C125A4-8743-6BF8-5A05-BE85778D4158> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleScript.framework/Versions/A/AppleScript
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <486E6C61-1197-CC7C-2197-82CE505102D7> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8011d000 -     0x7fff8011efff  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <EA4D1607-2BD5-2EE2-2A3B-632EEE5A444D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff8016d000 -     0x7fff8046bfe7  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.4 (???) <263AD497-F4CC-9610-E7D3-B95CF6F02030> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff80472000 -     0x7fff804befff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff804bf000 -     0x7fff80574fe7  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <8C36373C-5473-3A6A-4972-BC29D504250F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff8071a000 -     0x7fff80784fe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <AF0EA96D-000F-8C12-B952-CB7E00566E08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff80791000 -     0x7fff80794ff7  com.apple.securityhi 4.0 (36638) <87868A3E-9341-1078-F00C-5E5972F01A4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SecurityHI.framework/Versions/A/SecurityHI
    0x7fff80795000 -     0x7fff808aefef  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <4F2DC233-7DD2-1204-CAA5-3E6524F0AB75> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
    0x7fff808b0000 -     0x7fff8092dfef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff80949000 -     0x7fff80949ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff80a2b000 -     0x7fff80ba2fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.4 (550.42) <770C572A-CF70-168F-F43C-242B9114FCB5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff80ba3000 -     0x7fff813adfe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FC941ECB-71D0-FAE3-DCBF-C5A619E594B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff813ae000 -     0x7fff813b4ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff813e6000 -     0x7fff813e9ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <609598E6-195D-E5D4-3B92-AE8D9768829C> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff813ea000 -     0x7fff813fefff  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <1EB1BD0F-C17F-55DF-B8B4-8E9CF99359D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff81480000 -     0x7fff814b9fef  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <561D0DCB-47AD-A12C-9066-70E4CBAD331C> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff816aa000 -     0x7fff816f4ff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <5170FCE0-ED6C-2E3E-AB28-1DDE3F628FC5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff8185b000 -     0x7fff81876ff7  com.apple.openscripting 1.3.1 (???) <9D50701D-54AC-405B-CC65-026FCB28258B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/OpenScripting
    0x7fff818b9000 -     0x7fff81901ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <98FC4457-F405-0262-00F7-56119CA107B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff81940000 -     0x7fff8194ffff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.1 (3.2.1) <E5D33870-27D2-E50B-9B35-16AA50369733> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff81950000 -     0x7fff81a67fef  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <B2FB9DA8-6EC9-FFBC-C919-C022B9CBEB73> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff81a98000 -     0x7fff81b51fff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <2C5ED312-E646-9ADE-73A9-6199A2A43150> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff81b52000 -     0x7fff81c07fe7  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.3 (4.6.3) <5A7360A8-D495-1E8D-C4B4-A363AF989ADE> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff81c08000 -     0x7fff81c33ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <87A0B228-B24A-C426-C3FB-B40D7258DD49> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff81e28000 -     0x7fff81e59fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <1A8E58CF-FA2F-14F7-A097-D34EEA8A7D03> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff81e5a000 -     0x7fff81e6cfe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff81e6d000 -     0x7fff81f2aff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 357 (357) <7B22626F-D544-1955-CC53-240F4CACEB4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff81f2b000 -     0x7fff81f30ff7  com.apple.CommonPanels 1.2.4 (91) <4D84803B-BD06-D80E-15AE-EFBE43F93605> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommonPanels.framework/Versions/A/CommonPanels
    0x7fff81f47000 -     0x7fff81f6ffff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <E9269069-93FA-2B71-F9BA-FDDD23C4A65E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff81fce000 -     0x7fff81fceff7  com.apple.Carbon 150 (152) <191B4F4B-8D06-796B-CA0C-782F06DD7BC7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff81fe1000 -     0x7fff81fe4fff  com.apple.help 1.3.1 (41) <54B79BA2-B71B-268E-8752-5C8EE00E49E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
    0x7fff81fe5000 -     0x7fff81ff9ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff81ffa000 -     0x7fff8201dfff  com.apple.opencl 12.3 (12.3) <D30A45FC-4520-45AF-3CA5-092313DB5D54> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff8201e000 -     0x7fff82024ff7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (6) <E8A1144C-5666-9840-4729-256FE69CDBDB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
    0x7fff82073000 -     0x7fff82088ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <1AE1FE8F-2204-4410-C94E-0E93B003BEDA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff82107000 -     0x7fff82148fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.5 (1.10.2) <FB39F09C-57BB-D8CC-348D-93E00C602F7D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff82149000 -     0x7fff823cffff  com.apple.security 6.1.1 (37594) <1B4E1ABD-1BB3-DA49-F574-0EEB23E73C6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff825d4000 -     0x7fff825d5ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.5 (1.6.5) <14F14B5E-9287-BC36-0C3F-6592E6696CD4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff825d6000 -     0x7fff825e5fff  com.apple.opengl 1.6.12 (1.6.12) <DE3F0528-7759-CDFD-A2CF-C51D3C9C8B39> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff825e6000 -     0x7fff8269cfff  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <99CB3A0F-64CF-1D16-70CD-8AED2EF06C30> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff8269d000 -     0x7fff826fdfe7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <D107CB8A-5182-3AC4-35D0-07068A695C05> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff8287e000 -     0x7fff828a4fe7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <DFA5DAC2-D1C6-D5ED-F95D-AC185E98B6E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff828eb000 -     0x7fff82c1ffff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.23 (861.23) <96465459-6536-3FD7-7504-B59D0390EEC5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff82ca9000 -     0x7fff82d28fe7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <6D8AD3F7-409D-512C-C5BE-66C64D1B8F3E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff82d29000 -     0x7fff82dd8fff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.10 (6.5.10) <6A159CD8-5C02-4528-C36F-6AFBFD61576B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff82fa2000 -     0x7fff83042fff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.2 (362.2) <A8EDC37C-1D40-5ED0-49BE-90EF110A6B3A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff83055000 -     0x7fff83213fff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <781E7B63-2AD0-E9BA-927C-4521DB616D02> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff83214000 -     0x7fff833cbfef  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.4 (3.0.4) <EE9DFBD6-6354-7C5A-F4C7-5FF782A7D992> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff833cc000 -     0x7fff833cdff7  libScreenReader.dylib ??? (???) <D98F32A6-4729-8040-AE06-76D2F4CF9BBB> /usr/lib/libScreenReader.dylib
    0x7fff833ce000 -     0x7fff833ceff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8340c000 -     0x7fff8340dff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <5952A9FA-BC2B-16EF-91A7-43902A5C07B6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8340e000 -     0x7fff83427fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <CCF79716-7CC6-2520-C6EB-A4F56AD0A207> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff83428000 -     0x7fff834a6fff  com.apple.CoreText 3.5.0 (???) <4D5C7932-293B-17FF-7309-B580BB1953EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff83730000 -     0x7fff83782ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.2 (???) <7C91D07D-FA20-0882-632F-0CAE4FAC2B79> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff8381c000 -     0x7fff83942fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.5 (1.6.5) <B51023BB-A5C9-3C65-268B-6B86B901BB2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff83943000 -     0x7fff83992ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.0 (6.0) <FE549581-6A40-BD28-24A4-68FA0B616780> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
    0x7fff83993000 -     0x7fff839a9fef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <42D3023A-A1F7-4121-6417-FCC6B51B3E90> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff839f7000 -     0x7fff83ac9fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.11.5 (454.11.5) <5D68598D-C138-C8B6-B6AC-B1F48B01E021> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff83bb1000 -     0x7fff83bb1ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <15DF8B4A-96B2-CB4E-368D-DEC7DF6B62BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff83bb2000 -     0x7fff83c4cfff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 4.4 (???) <395849EE-244A-7323-6CBA-E71E3B722984> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff83c4d000 -     0x7fff83c63fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.0.1 (6.0.1) <09ABF2E9-D110-71A9-4A6F-8A61B683E936> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
    0x7fff84091000 -     0x7fff841b2fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <48AEAFE1-21F4-B3C8-4199-35AD5E8D0613> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff841bb000 -     0x7fff841d1fe7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.10 (207.10) <458F0259-6EDC-16BA-E6AA-1CEED002D188> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff841e4000 -     0x7fff84269ff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <CDFE82DD-D811-A091-179F-6E76069B432D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff8426a000 -     0x7fff84607fe7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.34) <C4AABD56-8C93-BAD0-4B27-7E9A2F0EAEE4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff8463e000 -     0x7fff8463eff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <96FB6BAD-5568-C4E0-6FA7-02791A58B584> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff84927000 -     0x7fff84932ff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <3D65E89B-FFC6-4AAF-D5CC-104F967C8131> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff84d5e000 -     0x7fff84d63fff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <A7BF2D68-F489-720C-E5A9-DC2B24DC5A21> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff84da8000 -     0x7fff851ebfef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff85efd000 -     0x7fff85f1dff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.9) <E7AFAAFA-8221-585B-85D0-171ADC490825> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff85f1e000 -     0x7fff85f23fff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <991F8197-FD06-2AF1-F99B-E448ED4FB2AC> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff85f24000 -     0x7fff85ffeff7  com.apple.vImage 4.0 (4.0) <354F34BF-B221-A3C9-2CA7-9BE5E14AD5AD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff8603a000 -     0x7fff8673706f  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <356D59D6-1DD1-8BFF-F9B3-1CE51D2F1EC7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff86738000 -     0x7fff86738ff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <4CCE5D69-F1B3-8FD3-1483-E0271DB2CCF3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff8687c000 -     0x7fff868c3ff7  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <923E33CC-83FC-7D35-5603-FB8F348EE34B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff86ab9000 -     0x7fff86b45fef  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <F43FDB02-CAA5-F8FF-C8D7-6665E7403ECE> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff86b46000 -     0x7fff86b63ff7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <667C3883-32A5-CCCC-8624-972B5DFD8EA4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff86b89000 -     0x7fff86baafff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F322F47-0584-CB7D-5B73-9EBD670851CD> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff86bab000 -     0x7fff86e2eff7  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.4 (751.42) <AF1E3050-3503-8714-8274-EA6BD6BE8A22> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff86e2f000 -     0x7fff86f6dfff  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <9DFE798D-AA52-6A9A-924A-DA73CB94D81A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff86f87000 -     0x7fff87148fff  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <F00A8B2F-84A0-0868-1047-3A13F9114864> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8718b000 -     0x7fff8718dfff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <6C974488-62D2-71BA-A45E-C764A0AF7354> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff871de000 -     0x7fff8721ffef  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <5DC41E81-32C9-65B2-5528-B33E934D5BB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff87229000 -     0x7fff87264fff  com.apple.AE 496.4 (496.4) <55AAD5CA-7160-7899-1C68-562ED8160DF7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff8728f000 -     0x7fff87293ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff873bd000 -     0x7fff873ceff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <97019C74-161A-3488-41EC-A6CA8738418C> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff873cf000 -     0x7fff87418fef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <CCE779A9-2467-A5AA-A558-691E43A1105F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff87419000 -     0x7fff8746eff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <A3CFF697-B9DB-A7E5-3B39-9DA9B34F0595> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
    0x7fff8746f000 -     0x7fff874fffff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <4175DC31-1506-228A-08FD-C704AC9DF642> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff87528000 -     0x7fff875e9fe7  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <8B12D37E-3A95-5A73-509C-3AA991E0C546> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff8766e000 -     0x7fff876bdfef  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <176B52ED-4F6C-D0C2-EABC-C032BFC3DFAA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff876be000 -     0x7fff876c4ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <EAD87C9F-BADC-7116-4ADD-0B0679459D24> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff87dce000 -     0x7fff87dd5fff  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <4200CFB0-DBA1-62B8-7C7C-91446D89551F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff87fba000 -     0x7fff8809ffef  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.9 (1.5.9) <27890B2C-0CD2-7C27-9D0C-D5952C5E8438> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff884b9000 -     0x7fff884c7ff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <27713C39-0E51-8F5A-877B-C5539C96A520> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff884c8000 -     0x7fff88ebefff  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.7 (1038.35) <9F4DF818-9DB9-98DA-490C-EF29EA757A97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff890fb000 -     0x7fff89120ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff89121000 -     0x7fff89123fff  com.apple.print.framework.Print 6.1 (237.1) <CA8564FB-B366-7413-B12E-9892DA3C6157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Print.framework/Versions/A/Print
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <F00A8B2F-84A0-0868-1047-3A13F9114864> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the script—the problem is quite possibly there instead.  Also, you might take a look at [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/rb-appscript/index.html), which is a way to interface with Apple Events (which is what AppleScript does) from Ruby or Python.

Comment: I've got two scripts - the real production script and a simple test script that I'm using in an attempt to weed out possible trouble spots.  The test script is literally one line: `"It worked!"`.  Applescript treats the last line as a return statement, so that string (should) get returned and saved in my `result` variable.

Comment: I'll check out appscript. Rewriting my applescript would certainly be a pain, though, so I'm going to hold out a little while longer for some other solution.

Comment: I'm got to your question since I'm having a similar problem using `daemons` (via delayed_jobs). The process gets the same exception (GetOurLSSessionIDInit) consistently. It happens if I use capistrano to start the process from another machine. If I log into that machine and start the process, it works just fine. I'm pretty sure the error has to do with how the Mac OS X window server determines which processes can show UI on the screen. I haven't figured out why yet. But I thought I'd share what I've learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out via testing about our issues. One question I had for you, is how are you starting the script? Is it started from logging on the machine and starting a terminal in the Mac OSX desktop screen? Or are you ssh'ing into the Mac and starting it from there.

On our daemon that was trying to use the Window Manager (firefox), if we started it via the Terminal.app from the logged in user. It would work fine. If we ssh'd in to start the script (which happens when you use Capistrano to start it) it would work fine until that ssh session was stopped. In the Console you can see the logs:

```
2/7/11 8:32:13 PM    com.apple.SecurityServer[22]    Session 0x22058d0 destroyed
2/7/11 8:32:13 PM    com.apple.SecurityServer[22]    Session 0x22058d0 dead
2/7/11 8:32:13 PM    com.apple.SecurityServer[22]    Killing auth hosts
```

This happens after we terminate the SSH session. After it terminates, we would get the errors like you did:

```
abort() called
LaunchServices: GetOurLSSessionIDInit() returned err #1, 
    securitySessionID == 0x0, vers=10600000 uid=501 euid=501
```

Instead of starting the script via ssh, we now have a LaunchAgent which will start the script based on WatchPaths with a ~/jobs/ directory. It works out well, and we can still restart the server with capistrano.

I would look in your logs to see if the SecurityServer is destroying a session right about the time the script fails. If so, then maybe you can figure out what is causing the timeout.

Comment: Bingo - I typically start the daemon via a remote SSH session. In a few quick tests here it seems I can reliably cause a crash by starting the daemon, waiting a few minutes to verify successfull execution, then exit the SSH session. I wasn't able to find that `SecurityServer` line in my console, though. I'd vote you up twice if I could, this bug has been hounding me for weeks!

Comment: Btw, for our use, the LaunchAgent works well to start the script. Since the LaunchAgent will start it inside the context of the logged in user. And, we have it watch a folder that we just touch a file and it will start the process. And I'm glad I could help. I spent most of yesterday trying to figure out why our process was failing, and figured I would document it somewhere.

Comment: Also, the log where the Session information is shown is the /private/var/log/secure.log  I see it when I use the console and via "All Messages"

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript I believe needs a window manager to run. Are you logged in on that machine, and does the Applescript get triggered as that user?

Comment: Yes. I'm logged in under the same user that the daemon is running as. I've also set it up to never go to sleep and never start the screensaver.